# How to set up MongoLab through Azure

Tags: azure, mlab

I am trying to set up a MongoLab instance for my Node.js web application. I would need some very simple instructions on how to do this...

I have tried to create a new instance through the Azure portal by doing the following:

1. New -> Data + Analytics -> MongoLab -> Create

[Doing this takes me to manage.windowsazure.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Z56.jpg)

2. I tried searching for MongoLab here, but it is nowhere to be found, and this leaves me pretty much stuck.

Comment: This is off-topic, as it's not programming-related. That said: You can still provision mLab MongoDB instances on Azure. Just needs to be done from mLab's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the exact same issue. Apparently the service [had been shut down](http://docs.mlab.com/20160622-maintenance-event/) on Azure Marketplace. Right now the status of MongoLab in Azure Portal is on "Preview" so it might come back into service in the future. It cites:

> mLab may, at a later date, join the new Azure Marketplace, but we
>   will first need to port its existing integration over to the newer
>   API.